# How to use <>(Not Equal To) in W TO PUT NOT EQUAL IN CASE THEN STATEMENT

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using CASE statement in SQL and I am trying to use `<>` in THEN statement.
But I'm getting an error when I use `<>` in THEN statement.
Here is my SQL code,

```
DECLARE @VAR CHAR(50) = 'SAMPLE'
SELECT * FROM [DB]
WHERE acct LIKE CASE WHEN @VAR = 'SAMPLE' THEN '88%' WHEN @VAR = 'SAMPLE2' THEN <> '88%' ELSE '%' END
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Case _expression_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rephrase this as:

```
SELECT *
FROM [DB]
WHERE
    (@VAR = 'SAMPLE'  AND acct LIKE '88%')     OR
    (@VAR = 'SAMPLE2' AND acct NOT LIKE '88%') OR
    (@VAR NOT IN ('SAMPLE', 'SAMPLE2'))
```

Note the third condition in the `WHERE` clause corresponding to the `WHERE acct LIKE '%'` else condition of your original `CASE` expression.  That is, if `@VAR` is not `SAMPLE` or `SAMPLE2`, then this alone would match a record.

Comment: the third condition means select all.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @VAR CHAR(50) = 'SAMPLE'
SELECT * FROM [DB]
WHERE (acct LIKE '88%' AND @VAR = 'SAMPLE')
      OR
      (acct NOT LIKE '88%' AND @VAR = 'SAMPLE2')
```